# Pose mode face bone - Insert key not working

Tags: animation

The face bones rotation in purple color and not able to insert key frame[image]

Comment: The bones related to face is in purple color and not able to insert key frames. Other body bones are working fine. This is on Blender 3.6. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I believe that means your rotation values are being controlled by drivers, you'll need to right click and remove the drivers in order to keyframe manually

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Analyzing how the drivers came there. Thanks again...